# Debugging in PhPStorm with XAMPP in OSx

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I have read this tutorial about config the XDebug with PhpStorm ([link](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/08/debugger-configuration-validation-with-phpstorm/))

Everything seems ok, but at the end of all, I have an error that says:

[image: Crazy Error]

I have the configuration of the PHP 5.5.6 and XDEBUG ok like you see in this screen shoot:

[image: Config PHP]

The server configurations seems ok too:

[image: Server configuration]

And the mappings and the connections seems ok too:

[image]
[image]

I have been working with that error 5 hours, and I don't have any idea where is the problem...

Thanks!!

Comment: @Prisoner That file is uploaded/copied to that location before executing such check and then immediately deleted afterwards.

Comment: I have tried a lot of possibilities... but nothing... :(

Comment: @chemitaxis I think you should find the file and fix your webPath.

Comment: find? where? This file is not mine... and the WebPath? But it's the webpath and works fine...

Comment: With Netbeans, the XDebug works fantastic...

Comment: `find / -name '_intellij_phpdebug_validator.php'` in your terminal @chemitaxis

Comment: Like @Prisoner said, this file is uploaded/copied to the location, I can see how it's copying to the folder... I can copy and paste to the desktop, an recopy again, but it's not solving my problem... thanks!!

Comment: 1) Can you execute .php files in browser? That script is just to make some basic checks to see if xdebug is installed and stuff like that -- nothing major. 2) Quite often in Mac and some Linux distros you will have separate configs for PHP files executed in CLI/terminal and via browser.